Story that mentions a religious group that rejects New Testament
This is a long shot I know as I don’t have many details but here goes nothing. I am looking for a science fiction story with a minor plot point that mentions a religious group that once was Christian but eventually rejected the New Testament and Jesus as false. The rejection was due to disillusionment with how long it was taking for the return of Jesus. This wasn’t necessarily a major plot point. It was a brief statement.

Actually it was a sci fi story. This was a minor plot point as mentioned, not the core idea.

I'm not seeing anything in the question to indicate that it's on-topic. What sort of sci-fi? What was the setting?

"Rejects Jesus and the New Testament". So...Jews?

Seems harsh to close

@fez - I'm not a huge fan of people posting seemingly mundane story-ID questions and then justifying it as on-topic by airily saying "I'm pretty sure it was sci-fi"

@Valorum nor am I, but that is the site policy and has been used to keep questions open that are just as on the fence as this one. If the OP says the original world was on-topic, then it’s on-topic. And if the story ends up not being on-topic, we can simply close it

@fez - I've voted to reopen (and downvoted the question). That seems a fair compromise

@DaveWelden - please try to edit in some more information about the story.  You are certain it was science fiction - so you are remembering something.  You might think it is not an important enough point, but sometimes small things make the difference in story id questions (and, in keeping a question open as on-topic).  Did something happen on another planet, for example?  Thanks.

@JohnRennie, you should turn that into an answer. I've cast the last missing reopen vote.

@DJClayworth Jews, Muslims, Mormons.  This question popped up this week and was an interesting read about what religions are "Christian" or not.

In David Weber's second book of the Honor Harrington series, The Honor of the Queen, we encounter a group called The Faithful who are described as:

There are a lot of points about their so-called religion that I can't get definitive information on, but I do know they've chopped the entire New Testament out of their Bibles because if Christ had really been the Messiah, technology never would have arisen on Old Earth, they wouldn't have been kicked off Grayson, and Woman would have been put in her proper place throughout the human community.

The Faithful are intolerant and violent and were exiled to a planet called Masada after they tried and failed to take over their original planet Grayson. I think The Faithful crop up again in later books but in a minor way.

Thanks John. It has been a quarter of a century and countless other stories since I read this series so unfortunately I had little additional context to provide. Glad you recognized it from such a meager clue. Current events brought it to mind but I couldn’t for the life of me recall where I encountered this story line.
